# Reduce flicker in python loading bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, carriage-return

Afternoon folks, I've got a loading bar in a python console app, and it flickers constantly during execution.  I managed to make it better by rearranging the print('\r') and print(bar) statements.  `print_progress_bar()` is as follows:

```
def print_progress_bar(percent):
    done_len = int(percent * progress_bar_length)
    bar = "["
    bar += "=" * done_len
    bar += ">"
    bar += " " * (progress_bar_length - done_len)
    bar += "] "
    bar += str(round(percent*100))
    bar += "%"
    print("\r", end='')
    print(bar+(" " * 5), end='')
```

I'm using it in a filesystem analysis, but here is a simple driver to test.

```
import time

progress_bar_length = 20
limit = 100

for i in range(1, limit):
    print_progress_bar(i/limit)
    time.sleep(0.1)
print("Done")
```

Any way to stop the flicker?

Comment: I have some doubts, that this is a topic depending on the programming language. Seems more in the area of operating system, shell window application and display driver.